# How fill grid to windows's height?

Tags: xaml, grid, uwp

This is template of my page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Show">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1.5" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CuurentTarget" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>


<Grid Style="{StaticResource JagermasterBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="PortraitOrientation">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="FluidPanel.(UIElement.Orientation)" Value="Horizontal"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="LandscapeOrientation"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource JagermasterSimpleStack}">
        <TextBlock Name="CuurentTarget" Style="{StaticResource JagermasterText}" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTarget}">
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Name="AdventureTimeButton" Style="{StaticResource JagermasterButton}" Content="Готов к новым приключениям" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="FluidPanel" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="List" Style="{StaticResource JagermasterSymbol}" Tapped="ListShowOrHide" Margin="5"/>
        <local:TargetsListManage x:Name="TargetsListManager"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I'm press "Restore down" grid(root) not fill the window. Bottom part just stay beyond the borders of window without scroll. I guess in this case I can add a binding for MaxSize. I hope exist another solution.
Here is screenshots for explaration: [as expect](https://yadi.sk/i/CTVeCSyyo2LDe) and [unexpect](https://yadi.sk/i/tXK0FNv6o2LSb)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want something like a footer that always stays at the bottom whatever your window might look like. Is that correct?

If so, this might be your solution:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--  Header  -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <!--  Place all header here  -->
    </Grid>

    <!--  Content  -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!--  Place all your scrollable elements here  -->
    </Grid>

    <!--  Footer  -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <!--  Place everything that needs to stay at the bottom here  -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

By defining `<RowDefinition/>` elements, you can give your child elements special heights like `Auto` (take as much space as you need) and `*` (take the remaining space).

Is that, what you need?

Comment: Close. I want to design page without footer. Root grid should filled to window in "restore down" mode same way as in "full size" mode (scroll appearead), but it not occured.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you draw me, what you exactly mean? What do you want to view? A view that always fills 100% of your window? The `Grid` does that by default. Inside the grid you can "fill" with the `RowDefinition`.

Comment: Did you see screensots that I've shared in first message? In first yoa can see a button and textbox after list. In second - bottom part is hiding and scrollbar doesnot work

Comment: Yeah, but I don't get, what your goal is? Do you want a) a `TextBox` that is always at the bottom of the PAGE or b) a `TextBox`, that is always at the bottom of the LIST, how long it ever might be (with scrolling working of course). You want b), right?